# Two imports div in map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, next.js

I am thinking about the possibility of embedding two imports among map().
My react code looks like this:

```
{this.state.dataExample.map(item => (                            
    <ItemsSection nameSection={item.name} />  

    item.data.map((post, index) => (

       <ItemsTasks
          key={index}
          title={post.name}
       />

    ))

))}
```

result:

```
// from ItemsSection
<div className="items-section-name">
    <div className="section-name">{nameSection}</div>
</div>
// from ItemsTasks
<div className="item-data">
    <div className="item-title">{title}</div>
<div className="item-data">
    <div className="item-title">{title}</div>
</div>
```

This code should illustrate what I would like to get. Trying to import a separate div for each 'element'. The above code reports a syntax error but I have no idea how I could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html),

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

You can use Fragment, short syntax `<></>` (It looks like empty tags),

```
{
  this.state.dataExample.map(item => (
    <>
      <ItemsSection nameSection={item.name} />  
      {
        item.data.map((post, index) => (
           <ItemsTasks
              key={index}
              title={post.name}
           />
        ))
      }
    </>                       
  ))
}
```

or you can import `Fragment` from `react` package,

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';


{
  this.state.dataExample.map(item => (
    <Fragment>
      <ItemsSection nameSection={item.name} />  
      {
        item.data.map((post, index) => (
           <ItemsTasks
              key={index}
              title={post.name}
           />
        ))
      }
    </Fragment>                       
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use React's [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
{
  this.state.dataExample.map(item => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ItemsSection nameSection={item.name} />  
      {
        item.data.map((post, index) => (
           <ItemsTasks
              key={index}
              title={post.name}
           />
        ))
      }
    </React.Fragment>                       
  ))
}
```